# What if employer says they'll pay "approximately" $$ without formal offer letter

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job, job-change, employer-relations

I live in Korea and just got an offer from a local company in Australia.
I really like the manager and CEO, especially they said they would sponsor my visa.
But they offered me a job without salary & benefit package. It wasn't even a formal offer letter, it was just an email (maybe because they're small company???)

I asked details about salary and the CEO told me they'll pay "approximately $$"... Not sure what that means, anyway it's less than what I thought so I asked for more and am now waiting for their response.

But I just can't stop thinking about this weirdness. What kind of employer uses "approximately $$"?

Comment: For the main question you just ask them to be specific which you mostly already did by asking for a specific amount. But beyond that it's hard to tell what it meant in this particular case and that makes this hard to answer. Could have been a sign of a very informal management style, an indicative number, a total package taking into account taxes, ...

Comment: What is the nature of the work? What is the job?

Answer (score 8):

It's not that uncommon to use it when it's not formal. It's a way of saying: "It's still open for negotiations".

I assume that as soon as the offer transforms to being formal in nature, it will be much more defined.

I have also seen it used from companies that pay you hourly. Some months are longer than others, so the pay will fluctuate a little.

Answer (score 1):

Did you apply for a position with this company? If not, how did they get your contact info + skillset + qualifications + etc ... ?

If they found you via legitimate means, or you applied for a position with this company, AND all of the communications so far have been informal, then as Sander Skovgaard Hansen has said ... it might not be a problem.

If this 'offer' came out of the blue, then it could be an indication that things are not what they seem. How much do you know about the company? Are they publicly traded? Do any of your trusted friends and/or colleagues know of them, or about them?

There are numerous work and Visa related scams going on all over the world, and it never hurts to be cautious.

In general, getting everything in writing is a good start ... and making sure that there are no un-written [or undocumented] conditions that are part of the package. If they're offering to sponsor your Visa, do some research and find out what issues may arise as part of that process, and find out if they expect you to pay for any [or all!] of the costs - not just the Government fees + paperwork, but any other costs, like lawyers, or even medical tests which may be required.

Perhaps I'm a paranoid old man ... but I would proceed with great caution.